sveltekit node-fetch localhost 'UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE'
I have been running a sveltekit app in Vercel for a couple of days without any problems. Debugging in VSC (Windows) via localhost was not a problem either until recently. Now when I debug I always have an issue with a 'first certificate'. The message is: 'UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE'. Sounds like an SSL problem. Changing the configuration setting to ssl_strict == false did not help.
I am fetching data from an Notion API.
Any clue, Thanks!
Before I published the Vercel app I did not have that problem.
Solution: The problem turned out to be my ESET Internet protection settings. I had to switch off HTTPS traffic scanning functionality.

Solution: The problem turned out to be my ESET Internet protection settings. I had to switch off HTTPS traffic scanning functionality.
